# Finding approximations of the velocity and acceleration given a sequence of spatial positions

Tags: sequences-and-series, physics

Given a sequence $\{\boldsymbol{x}^{k}\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}} \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that it converges to $\boldsymbol{x}$, I need to find vectors $\boldsymbol{v}$ and $\boldsymbol{a}$ and sequences $\{\boldsymbol{v}^{k}\}, \{\boldsymbol{a}^{k}\}\subset \mathbb{R}^{n} $ and $\{t_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\subset \mathbb{R}^{*}_{+} = \{t \in\mathbb{R}: t>0\}$ such that $$\boldsymbol{x}^{k} = \boldsymbol{x} + t_k \boldsymbol{v}^{k} + \dfrac{t_k^2}{2}\boldsymbol{a}^{k},$$ $\boldsymbol{v}^{k}\rightarrow \boldsymbol{v}$,  $\boldsymbol{a}^{k}\rightarrow \boldsymbol{a}$ and $t_k \rightarrow 0$. Note that this resembles the determination of the velocity and acceleration of a particle that passes through $\boldsymbol{x}^{k}$ over the time at the position  $\boldsymbol{x}^{*}$ . Is this possible?

---

**Motivation from optimization**: Let us consider the optimization problem \begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{c c}
\text{minimize}_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n}  & f(x) \\
\text{subject to} & \begin{aligned}
      x \in \Omega.\\ 
     \end{aligned} 
\end{array}
\end{equation*} The first order tangent cone at $x$, say $T(x)$ is given by the set of vectors $d$ such that $x+t_k d^{k} \in \Omega$ with $d^{k}\rightarrow d$ and $t_k \rightarrow 0.$ Hence, a natural definition for a second order tangent set would be the set of pairs $(v,a)$ such that $$x+t_k v^{k}+ \dfrac{t_k^{2}}{2} a^{k} \in \Omega$$ such that $v^{k} \rightarrow v$, $a^{k} \rightarrow a$ and $t_{k}\rightarrow 0.$ Now, this definition gives rise to other questions like

> Does this notion of second order tangent set is enough to model a quadratic feasible set?

Solving this problem, would help me to understand better how this question could be answered.

Comment: This is a great problem to solve. For my curiosity, and for the rest of the community, could you please tell us where you found it?

Comment: Note that you probably want to require that time moves forward, that is $t_k\leq t_{k+1}$.